# How to add cytoscape extensions in Angular

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Im trying to implement cytoscape extensions in Angular 8

npm install cytoscape-edge-editing
Cytoscape work fine.

1.app.ts

```js
import * as cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import * as edgeBendEditing from 'cytoscape-edge-editing';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';


let cytoscape = require('cytoscape');
let jquery = require('jquery');
let edgeBendEditing = require('cytoscape-edge-editing');

edgeBendEditing( cytoscape, jquery );
cytoscape.use(edgeBendEditing);
```

1. angular.json

```js
     "scripts": [
              "node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js",
              "node_modules/cytoscape-edge-editing/cytoscape-edge-editing.js",
              "node_modules/query/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

The error in browser is as below.

ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More]

Comment: where is `$` there is no `$` sign on your codes. Also, the order of scripts is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to amend your imports.
write:

> "import cytoscape from 'cytoscape'"
>
> "import $ from 'jquery'"

after correcting your typo mistake as mentioned on above solution

> "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js".

Angular will give error following direct import, for it you have to add

> "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

in tsconfig.json file under

> "experimentalDecorators": true,

line and in tsconfig.app.json file under

> "types": [],

line.
For jquery to be imported in angular you have to add following line (if not there) at the end in index.d.ts file which is under your-project/node_modules/@types/jquery (assuming you have mpm installed jquery):

> export = jQuery;

Then you will be able to register jquery easily using:

> cytoscape.use($);

it will resolve the error you are facing. But jquery works with the extension it is being used with, for that you have to register that extension with jquery like this:

> cytoscape.use(edgeBendEditing,$)

This statement will give error of overloading arguments, for it you have to amend the index.d.ts file of cytoscape under your-project/node_modules/@types/cytoscape:

> function use(module: Ext): void;

to this:

> function use(module: Ext, module2?: Ext): void;

It'll solve your problem.
I have used contextmenus using jquery with the same ammendments, hope that works for you as I was facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in "scripts" part. It should be "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js".

Comment: yes correct. i changed to 
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"

still problem persist
$ not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hooks by below method

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    cytoscape.use(dagre);
    cytoscape.use(popper);
}
```