# How to Use Cytoscape.Js Extension in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I tried to use CytoscapeJS with an extension - [Cytoscape-Node-Editing](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-node-editing) - in a Typescript project. After reference [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216929/how-to-add-cytoscape-extensions-in-angular), I changed **a line in `@types/cytoscape`** However, I am lost in dark to set up `index.d.ts` because I am unfamiliar with it, so would like to got any advise, how to implement it? Or any problems with other places? Sincerely.

@types/cytoscape/index.d.ts

```
function use(module: Ext, module2?: Ext, module3?: Ext): void;
```

canvas.ts

```js
import cytoscape from "cytoscape";
import $ from 'jquery';
import Konva from 'konva';
import nodeEditing from "cytoscape-node-editing";

cytoscape.use(nodeEditing, Konva, $);

var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({ 

... 

}) 

cy.nodeEditing();
```

Then got Error message

```
Argument of type 'typeof Konva' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ext'.
  Type 'typeof Konva' provides no match for the signature '(cytoscape: (options?: CytoscapeOptions | undefined) => Core): void'.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the usage instructions at: https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-node-editing your code should read more like this:

```
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import $ from 'jQuery';
import nodeEditing from 'cytoscape-node-editing';
import konva from 'konva';

nodeEditing( cytoscape, $, konva ); // register extension
```

I'm unfamiliar with cytoscape, but it's pretty rare to have to mess with the `.d.ts` files the @types/packages contain. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems that jquery and konva need to be registered to a cytoscape instance that having `nodeEditing()`, but `.use()` defined in @types/cytoscape/index.d.ts does not take only one argument, so I cannot register those to the instance...

Comment: @moriaki `nodeEditing( cytoscape, $, konva)` handles everything for you, you should not have to modify the `index.d.ts` file. (https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-node-editing/blob/master/src/cytoscape-node-editing.js Line 240) Also, it doesn't look like `cytoscape` uses jquery and Konva directly, only the `cytoscape-node-editing` extension, so you shouldn't be passing jquery and konva into the `.use()` function. I tried recreating an environment, but also ran into an issue. What are you using to render the frontend?